# Myeclipse 2015 failed ro start after runing it with clean mode?

Tags: linux, eclipse

I'm using myeclipse 2015 with ubuntu 14.10,and it's so slow for that I executed it in the clean mode:

```
./myeclipse -clean
```

and from that time, it failed to start...

```
!SESSION 2015-03-13 16:56:19.404 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -clean

!ENTRY com.genuitec.eclipse.themes.dark.core 4 0 2015-03-13 16:57:00.635
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/internal/preferences/PreferencesOSGiUtils
        at com.genuitec.eclipse.themes.dark.core.internal.DarkExtensionsManagerImpl.initialize(DarkExtensionsManagerImpl.java:88)
        at com.genuitec.eclipse.themes.dark.core.internal.DarkExtensionsManagerImpl.weave(DarkExtensionsManagerImpl.java:128)
        at com.genuitec.eclipse.themes.dark.core.internal.DarkWeaver.weave(DarkWeaver.java:16)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.weaving.WovenClassImpl.call(WovenClassImpl.java:160)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.notifyHookPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:1280)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.notifyHooksPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:1263)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.weaving.WovenClassImpl.callHooks(WovenClassImpl.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.weaving.WeavingHookConfigurator.processClass(WeavingHookConfigurator.java:56)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:616)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:588)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:527)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:391)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at com.genuitec.eclipse.themes.dark.core.internal.DarkExtensionsManagerImpl.initialize(DarkExtensionsManagerImpl.java:88)
        at com.genuitec.eclipse.themes.dark.core.internal.DarkExtensionsManagerImpl.weave(DarkExtensionsManagerImpl.java:128)
        at com.genuitec.eclipse.themes.dark.core.internal.DarkWeaver.weave(DarkWeaver.java:16)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.weaving.WovenClassImpl.call(WovenClassImpl.java:160)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.notifyHookPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:1280)
```

Why did this happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have a corrupt installation. If you haven't yet sorted this, I suggest you reinstall MyEclipse 2015.